# Converting a PHP if/else statement to use ternary format

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I want to convert this if/else statement to ternary format:

```
function session_active()
{
  if ($_SESSION['p_logged_in']) { 
    return true; 
  } 
  else { 
    return false; 
  }; 
}
```

I tried:

```
function session_active()
{
  ($_SESSION['p_logged_in'] ? true : false);
}
```

but it always returns false.

I am looking at the examples at http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples and this seems correct as far as I can see from the examples. Why does it always return false?

Comment: why can't you just `return $_SESSION['p_logged_in'];` ?

Comment: in that case, it would be (bool)$_SESSION['p_logged_in'], just to cover your butt based on the value of that variable

Comment: FYI and go further : The function [session_status()](http://php.net/session_status) can be helpful if you have PHP => 5.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php isnt ruby, you have to return that value from the ternary.

to elaborate in more detail...

```
function session_active()
{
  return ($_SESSION['p_logged_in'] ? true : false);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try to simple `return` the `$_SESSION['p_logged_in']` value :-

```
function session_active()
{
  return  (bool)$_SESSION['p_logged_in'];
}
```

Comment: Since the author wants to see a tenary statement, the more verbose way to write this is return $_SESSION['p_logged_in'] ? true : false; But since $_SESSION['p_logged_in'] resolves to a boolean it is cleaner to return that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function session_active() {
   return (isset($_SESSION['p_logged_in'])) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to correct your logic add `return` in front of your statment
to simplify it do:  `return (bool)$_SESSION['p_logged_in'];`

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `$_SESSION['p_logged_in'] === true` vs `$_SESSION['p_logged_in'] != null`, by returning $_SESSION['p_logged_in'] could in affect be more than what it is testing for.